# Linq: Inner join two tables and return as json for jquery datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatables

Im new here in using datatables and ajax in MVC ASP.net. Im having problem and its to difficult for me to solve this. I trying to join two tables as like the title says and return the result to json and display to datatable. but im getting an error of "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.". Any help would be great for me to learn this language. thank you

Here is my code

```
public ActionResult Rooms()
        {
            using (RoomReservationEntities db = new RoomReservationEntities())
            {
                var room_query = from room in db.Rooms
                        join roomType in db.Room_Type
                        on room.RoomType_id equals roomType.RoomType_id
                        select new { room.Room_id, room.Room_name, roomType.RoomType, roomType.Room_rate };

                return Json(new { data = room_query }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

my cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Rooms";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminMasterPage.cshtml";
}

<h2>Rooms</h2>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<h2>AdminRooms</h2>

<div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto">
    <table id="myDatatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Room Name</th>
                <th>Room Type</th>
                <th>Room Rate</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

    </table>
</div>


@section scritps{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var oTable = $('#myDatatable').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": '/Admin/Rooms',
                "type": "get",
                "datatype":"json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Room_name", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "RoomType", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Room_rate", "autoWidth": true }
            ]

        })
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are using the "using" block the using block call Dispose method as soon as it finds closing bracket.
The other reason may because Linq query doesn't fire until it is accessed by ToList() or enumerated. In your code, There is not such method you can check following code:

```html
public ActionResult Rooms()
        {
            using (RoomReservationEntities db = new RoomReservationEntities())
            {
                var room_query = (from room in db.Rooms
                        join roomType in db.Room_Type
                        on room.RoomType_id equals roomType.RoomType_id
                        select new { room.Room_id, room.Room_name, roomType.RoomType, roomType.Room_rate }).ToList();

                return Json(new { data = room_query }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

You can find more about Linq query Early binding and Late binding

Comment: Thank you so much sir. You save my day